# Locking table when using update on innodb table

Tags: mysql

If I run the following query

```
update phppos_people set phone_number = alphanumplus(phone_number);
```

What locks will it cause? I am pretty sure read lock won’t happen, but what about update or write?

This is for MySQL 8 innodb. The alphanum plus is a function I defined

---

If the following query is used, will it be table lock or row lock ?

```
update phppos_people 
set phone_number = alphanumplus(phone_number) 
WHERE phone_number REGEXP '[^0-9A-Za-z+]';
```

Answer (score 0):

[The LOCK clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-performance.html#innodb-online-ddl-locking-options)

DML do rows lock only, but since you are not using any where clause all the rows will be locked (full table scan) for other DDL and DML processes until the transaction is committed.

You are right about `read lock won't happen`. It will not cause read lock (tested on one of my large innodb tables).

If you want concurrent DML to be executed use `LOCK=NONE` as described in `The LOCK clause` link

---

**Edit**

> If the following query is used, will it be table lock or row lock ?

Since MySQL doesn't use index on the REGEXP function it has to do a table scan , so a table lock will occur for (DML, DDL processes).

Comment: Where do I add lock=NONE in my update query?

Comment: It appears this might be a table level option which I don’t want to do

Comment: What about changing my question to this Update phppos_people set phone_number = alphanumplus(phone_number) WHERE phone_number REGEXP '[^0-9A-Za-z+]';